# scrollview a table under full scroll viewd intent (view)

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, scrollview, tableview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:text="Mesaj Başlığı"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textExtendHeader"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="000dp">
                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:gravity="top">
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/ListC"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F" />
                    </ScrollView>
                </TableRow>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i got two scrollview elements;
first whole pages goes and up while scroll and second scrollview element is a tableview, when i try to scrollview table, doesnt sense only whole page scrolls.
is there a trick to scroll separate table view and page?

Comment: Why you have put a listview inside a scroll view ?List view has its own scroll

Comment: think a page scrollview got elements image, listview map and soemthing else, scroll up and down but if there any other scrolled thing like listview or map, they doesnt make sense how you got update?